# Randomly replace a set number of cells with a value from a unique list

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, excel, ascii, random

I have an Excel/ASCII table (300x300) where I want to randomly select a certain number/percentage of cells and replace that value with a number from a list (0.131, 0.149, 0.052). Is there a way to do this? I am going to convert the ASCII file to a Raster. Or is there a way to do this in ArcMap?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, Boolean questions, especially in the form "Is there a way to do this?" are not likely to fare well here (the answer is usually, "There are many ways").  The "Focused Problem/Best Answer" model used here works best when the basic research is done elsewhere, or by mining existing questions which have similar terms, and new questions are raised here when you are stuck in the middle of a solution.  At that point, you should specify the *exact* software you are using and include your code.

Comment: Are we really that uptight on this site that we are going to bust someone's chops for asking "is there a way to do this" rather than asking "how can I do this?"  You really can't tell that the writer isn't asking a "Boolean question"? The writer has specifically said he has "an Excel/ASCII table" which, at least to me says he's currently using Excel. He further asks if there's a way to do it in ArcMap. Thus he has named two specific software packages.

Comment: until the question is opened for answers, here's a brief sketch: create a new 300x300 table. In every cell enter the formula = rand(), which places a random number between 0 and 1. Now create yet another 300x300 table. Let's say you want x% of those cells with one of the three numbers you listed. Create an if formula that tests whether the random number in the corresponding cell in the table of random numbers is <x/3. If true, pick your first value. If false, check if <2x/3, in which case pick the second. If false, check if <x, pick the third. Otherwise pick the number from the original table.

Comment: I also think this is a good question, voted to reopen it

Comment: There are a number of issues with this question: It doesn't demonstrate prior research and effort to solve the problem. It doesn't adequately define the problem. Solving the issue in Excel (with VBA) is more of a Stack Overflow issue. Asking about Excel *or*. ArcGIS makes this two different questions, which violates the "One question per Question" policy. And the question is a coding question without a coding attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Pure ArcGIS workflow assuming you converted your ASCII to raster.

- Calculate total number of points excluding NODATA:

  arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("""Con( ~IsNull("original"),1)""", "D:/Scratch/c_count")
- Create random raster to cut percentage from

  arcpy.CreateRandomRaster_management("D:/Scratch", "random", "UNIFORM 0.0 1.0")
- get exact number of cells = percentage. In below example 10%. Check raster table and repeat if necessary by slightly changing threshold, until perfect match found

  arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("""Con("random" <= 0.10,"c_count")""", "D:/Scratch/to_points")
- Convert raster to points and add field to populate:

  arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(in_raster="to_points",

  arcpy.AddField_management("to_raster", "fromLIST","FLOAT")

Populate field (Python parser) using expression:

```
def aRand():
 aList=[0.131,0.149,0.052]
 n=int(arcgis.rand("INTEGER 0 2"))
 return aList[n]
```

## -----------------

```
aRand()
```

- Convert points to raster and combine with original:

  arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion("to_raster", "fromLIST", "D:/Scratch/topONE")
  arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("""Con(IsNull("topONE"),"original","topONE")""", "D:/Scratch/result")